# Delete rows that don't match National Insurance Number format using regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm fairly new to R after switching from spss, but need to use R for this project. I am reading in data from an excel file of people and the unique identifier for each person is their UK National Insurance Number, but i need to delete any rows that don't contain the NINO in the correct format, i.e. AB123456A.

Some types of "NINOs" that are listed in the data, which i need to remove as they don't match the format exactly.

- ******69B
- cms1234
- BCN8888855555
- AB 123456 A
- NA

I found this regex online to validate the format of the NINO.

> /^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-D]{1}$/i

I've tried running it in the code below, but while no error messages are displayed, it doesn't remove any rows from the dataset either.

```
DEP_Programmes %>% 
  filter(!grepl("/^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-D]{1}$/i", DEP_Programmes$NiNo)) %>%
  count(Programme)
```

Any suggestions? Please and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> The format of the [National Insurance] number is two prefix letters,
>   six digits and one suffix letter. [...] Neither of the first two letters can be D, F, I, Q, U
>   or V. The second letter also cannot be O. The prefixes BG, GB, NK, KN,
>   TN, NT and ZZ are not allocated. [...] The suffix letter is either A,
>   B, C, or D
>   ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Insurance_number#format)).

So the regex you found is almost correct but the leading and trailing characters should be removed. A little test:

```
regex <- "^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-D]{1}$"

test <- c("AB123456A", "******69B", "cms1234", "BCN8888855555",
          "AB 123456 A", NA, "QQ123456C")
grepl(regex, test)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Check [this cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) for reference.

Inside your original code this should look like that:

```
DEP_Programmes %>% 
  filter(grepl("^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-D]{1}$", NiNo)) %>% # omit DEP_Programmes$ inside dplyr pipe
  count(Programme)
```

Note that within filter, `TRUE` values are kept and `FALSE` values are removed. By adding a leading `!` you invert the selection, meaning that your `TRUE` values are removed (which I understand you don't want). That's the reason why with your original code nothing was removed. Since the regex was not the r-flavour of regex but some other language, all strings were `FALSE`. Inverting this led to all being kept.

Answer (score 1):

The regex passed into `grepl` does not take any delimiters, and also if you want case insensitive behavior you should use the `ignore.case` option rather than `/i`:

```
DEP_Programmes %>% 
    filter(!grepl("^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-D]{1}$", NiNo, ignore.case=TRUE)) %>%
    count(Programme)
```

Note: Your current regex looks a lot like either PHP or JavaScript.